# plotting roc curve in R problem: x axis is in opposite direction

Tags: r, roc

I am coding with R and trying to plot roc curve after randomForest classification :

```
rf.roc<- roc(Y , Votes)
  file1=paste( "cv_average", Cancer,".AUC.RF" , ".pdf" , sep="" )
  pdf(file=file1  ,width = 5 , height = 5 )
  plotRF<-plot.roc(rf.roc,main=paste(Cancer , " vs. others",  " average of cv RF" , sep="")
               ,col=1,lwd=4, cex.lab=1.5 , cex.main=1.1 , cex.lab=1.1)
    text(x=0.7 , y=0.65 , label=paste("mean_accuracy=" , round(acc.RF , digits = 4) , sep="")  , cex=1 ,font=2)
    text(x=0.7 , y=0.8  ,label=paste("AUC= ",round( auc(rf.roc), digits = 4) , sep = "") , cex=1 , font=2 )
  print(plotRF)
  dev.off()
```

[image]
as you can see  x axes is in opposite direction!

```
rf.roc
Data: Votes in 557 controls (Y 0) < 120 cases (Y 1).
Area under the curve: 0.9966
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me fix this

Comment: Please share the data set or part of it in order to make reproducible your code.

Comment: well my data set is rather big. 'Votes' and 'Y 'are  vectors of length 677. can you suggest a way to share them here?

Comment: I think just 40 rows are enough. Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: What do you mean "in opposite direction"? Please clarify what you're expecting exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the True Positive Rate (of those whom are classified positive how many are actually positive) versus the True Negative Rate (of those whom are classified negative how many are actually negative). The graph makes sense the way it is no?